# global table of clients C : Chatroom

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I created a client/server chatroom in C. I need to put in a global table of all clients connected so that I can send every message the server receives to all the clients connected. I can't figure out how to do this. I assume I have to create a struct of some sort and add every specific socket descriptor for each thread I spawn. Then I have to send my message to every specific SD in that struct.

I don't know how to code this and wanted to see if anyone could show me some example code of what I have to write after every connection is made and what I have to write to then send my messages to every thread. My server code is below if needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
void *
client_session_thread(void * arg)
{
    int     SD;
    char    request[2048];
    char    message[2048] = "server receives input: ";
    int     chatfile;
    char    msgr[50000];

    SD = *(int *)arg;
    free (arg);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    chatfile = open("chathistory.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0666);
    close(chatfile);

    chatfile = open("chathistory.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    read(chatfile,msgr,sizeof(msgr));
    write(SD, msgr, strlen(msgr));

    while (read(SD, request, sizeof(request)))
    {
        strcat(message, request);
        strcat(message,"\n");
        fprintf(stdout, message);
        write(SD,request,strlen(request));
        write(chatfile,request,strlen(request));
        strcpy(request,"");
        strcpy(message, "server receives input: ");
        bzero(request, sizeof(request));
        bzero(message,sizeof(message));
    }
    close(SD);
    close(chatfile);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

//create a socket. SD is my socket. 
    struct addrinfo     addrinfo;
    struct addrinfo *   result;
    char message[256];
    int SD;
    int FD;
    pthread_t ignore;
    int * FDpntr;
    int on = 1;

    addrinfo.ai_flags = 0;
    addrinfo.ai_family = AF_INET;       // IPv4 only
    addrinfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Want TCP/IP
    addrinfo.ai_protocol = 0;       // Any protocol
    addrinfo.ai_addrlen = 0;
    addrinfo.ai_addr = NULL;
    addrinfo.ai_canonname = NULL;
    addrinfo.ai_next = NULL;

    if (getaddrinfo("clamshell.rutgers.edu", "5700", &addrinfo, &result) !=0)
    {
        printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem with getaddrinfo\x1b[0m\n");  
    }
//Create socket
    SD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (SD == -1)
    {
        printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem creating socket\x1b[0m\n");
    }
//Bind the socket to our specified IP and port
    if (setsockopt(SD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) ==-1)
    {
        printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem with sockopt\x1b[0m\n");
        freeaddrinfo(result);
    return -1;
    }
    if (bind(SD, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem binding socket\x1b[0m\n");
    }
    //first we bind our socket and then recast our address just like in client
//Listen function listens for connections
    if (listen(SD, 20) == -1)
        {
            printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem with listen\x1b[0m\n");
            close(SD);
            return 0;
        }
    else
        {
//Accept function for accepting incoming connection
        //sos = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        //while (FD = accept(SD, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&sos))
        while ((FD = accept(SD,0,0)) != -1)
        {
            FDpntr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
            *FDpntr = FD;
            if (pthread_create(&ignore, NULL, client_session_thread, FDpntr) != 0)
            {
                printf("\x1b[1;31mProblem creating thread\x1b[0m\n");
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        close(SD);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean an array instead of a struct? Structs are fairly rigid. An array would be expandable in the sense that it could hold 1-n socket descriptors.

Comment: Yes an array would be more appropriate. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

suggest implement a separate file.

That file would have entry points:

```
initializeClientTable() 
destroyClientTable()
addClient()
deleteClient(),
getClient()
```

The getClient() function would return a client.

it would have a parameter that (probably an enum value) that indicates to `get the first client` or `get the next client` from the ClientTable

When at the end of the ClientTable, return an indication of such event.

The ClientTable could easily be implemented as a linked list.